# deserialize class to json

Tags: asp.net-core, deserialization

in aspnet core
there is a service controller to deserialize string and enums.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
  options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
}
```

Is there also a deserializer to serialize any class?.

Answer (score 0):

apperantly a future of Misscrosoft json to disable by default unless

```
 options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
```